# How to convert .nc4 files to .nc using R?

Tags: r, convert, netcdf

I have thousands of files with the .nc4 file extension and I'd like to convert them to .nc format using the programming language R.

I am using the `ncdf4` package to read my data, but  I've got no clue about how I should proceed with the conversion.

Does anyone know how to do it, or where I can find helpful information on this?

Comment: Please show us how you read your data and what elements are in it. What do you mean by ".nc" format? That sounds like netCDF to me, which your .nc4 files probably are. So why are you doing this?

Comment: Note that there is no convention that I am aware of that says that NetCDF4 files should be named `.nc4`, while version 3 should be named `.nc`. The extension is just a part of the name and does *not* necessarily reflect what the file contains. Are you asking how to rename the files, how to convert them to Netcdf classic (v3), or both?